# Claiming compensation for late service of Eurotunnel

Tags: uk, trains, france, compensation, eurotunnel

Yesterday I was coming back from France using the [Euro Tunnel](http://www.eurotunnel.com/uk/home/), and they had substantial delays of about 90 minutes. Hence the question: when is it possible to claim any compensation from them for the delay? What is the procedure and what are the possible compensation levels?

EDIT: Clarification - I took the car-train.

Answer (score 11):

If you have a legitimate complaint and have the supporting documentation, you can send a detailed description of your complaint to...

```
Customer Relations Team
Eurotunnel
UK Terminal
Ashford Road
Folkestone
CT18 8XX
```

They will reply within 3 working days with an acknowledgement.  And their investigation will last a maximum of 28 days after which they will get back to you.  If you are not satisfied with their response to your complaint, you can escalate.  An explanation of how to escalate comes when they reply.

It's best to send your notification of complaint as soon as possible.

If your complaint does not require supporting evidence and you expect the investigation to be straight-forward, you can simply email them at customer.relations@eurotunnel.com

If they decide to remedy your complaint with compensation, they will use the relevant UK consumer protection guidelines and they have the option to compensate in kind.

---

### Update 2 September 2015

Eurotunnel delays are becoming [increasingly severe](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-34128448), and this may prompt them to revise their complaints procedure or to be more captious in processing compensation claims.

If this eventuates, Travellers should be advised that claims will need to be rigorously documented and the 'small print' may contain newly worded exculpatory clauses.

See also: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-34125950

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you went by train (I'm not sure if the same rules apply to the car-train) you should be entitled to 25% refund if you were between 1h and 2h late at arrival, according to the [European Rail Passenger Rights](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/rail/index_en.htm).

That website also states you should claim that refund from the railway - many have some online forms for that, [Eurostar has information here](http://www.eurostar.com/uk-en/travel-info/service-information/disruption-compensation). In any case they will have some address for complaints listed - a letter to that address should do.

Update - the EU rail passengers rights don’t apply to a shuttle service

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more precise - I went by the car-train (Eurotunnel vs Eurostar :)

Comment: @Grzenio oddly enough while the Eurostar has clear details, the EuroTunnel does not - and I couldn't find anything on compensation for it right now. Writing to the company stating your case and asking for compensation under the Rail Passenger Rights should never hurt though.

Answer (score 0):

We were delayed by 3 1/2 hours last night!  Having read the relevant Ts and Cs (and note that Eurotunnel is not governed by either the air or train regulators for delay claims), you can only claim expenses if you are forced to stay in a hotel overnight because the trains aren't running till the next morning.

Comment: Do you have an online source for your affirmation that you can share?

Comment: There is still a fair chance they will offer you some compensation if you write a complaint - this is exactly what happened in our case.